# FFmpeg scaling up video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg using a video of resolution 886x1820. I would like to create a thumbnail of 1280x720. Is this possible with no padding and shrinktofit using FFmpeg ?

Comment: Yes, but image will be stretched.

Comment: try this ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -r 15 -s 320x240 -an destination.mp4